# Blending messages in and out with control or jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, text, blending, fading

What would you suggest, if I wanted to blend text messages in and out (fade in and out) from codebehind ?
My problem is the following:
I have a couple of modalpopups in which I have UpdatePanels running and when the user submits data, I want to show messages (not javascript's alert) like "Saved." as pure text, that is faded in and out, thus doesn't require space. (similar to having a `<p>`-tag set to display: none and display:block with fade effect)

I know that I could use a Label and set its Visibility to true or false, but that's not what I want to do. (-> a dirty solution without fade effect)

Important is that I do this from codebehind...
Is there some sort of Asp.NetControl that would do the trick ? Or will I have to use jquery from codebehind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small list of jQuery plugins for this:

http://webtoolkit4.me/2009/08/13/jquery-growl-likenotification-systems/

Comment: thank ! I did try to google something like this, but obviously used the wrong keywords and descriptions of what I was looking for.
I guess I would have to code a codebehind solution myself...

Answer (score 0):

Im using **Gritter** on at least 2 projects and It's doing pretty well so far.

http://boedesign.com/demos/gritter/

Comment: thx for the suggestion. Been trying all existing notification plugins and ended up simply using regular jquery to fade a nicely styled div class in and out. Those plugins are way too "over-the-top" for my project.